# What should I set for the ActiveMQTopic properties in bean definition?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ as my JMS broker. I have the following class as my message sender:

```
public class MyMessageSender {
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    private Topic topic;

    public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

    public void setTopic(Topic topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }
}
```

In my Spring bean configuration file, I have:

```
<bean id="customerMessage" class="com.example.MyMessageSender">
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jsmTemplateBean" />
    <property name="topic" ref="topicBean" />
</bean>

<bean id="jsmTemplateBean" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryBean" />
</bean>

<bean id="topicBean" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
    <constructor-arg value="**What to put here as the constructor arg?**" />
</bean>
```

I looked up the javadoc of [ActiveMQTopic](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQTopic.html). There is a constructor with a `String` as its argument. So what should I put in the bean definition of `org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic`? The javadoc doesn't say anything about that parameter. I guess maybe it's the Topic name? But how do I specify it in ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually the Topic name. With `ActiveMQ` you don't need to explicitly setup or configure the `queues/topics` which you'll need. If you try to publish or subscribe from any queue or topic it will be silently created on the fly. Sometimes people put destinations into `JNDI` so that they can be pulled out by their application without needing to know the real, physical `queue/topic` name. This is fine, you can just add the `ActiveMQQueue` and `ActiveMQTopic` objects into `JNDI` if you want but it is not necessary.

So if for example you are using that configuration :

```
<bean id="topicBean" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
    <constructor-arg value="my.topic" />
</bean>
```

Every application that are subscribed to the topic `my.topic` will receive message that is send with the `topicBean` as a destination. You don't have to specified the name anywhere else.

Here is the [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-create-new-destinations.html) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very easy since I don't need to create a destination before I publish/subscribe to a queue/topic. But I noticed that I can use the ActiveMQ's admin web console at `http://localhost:8161/admin/` to create a topic/queue beforehand. Is it equivalent to setting the topic name in the bean definition file? If that's the case, then I don't need to use admin console to create topic/queue, right?

Comment: You can create the topic beforehand if you want. If you don't it will be create the first time you publish or subscribe to it.